# Modelica class diagrams

Tags: class-diagram, modelica

I am looking for a tool that can (automatically) create class diagrams like this one from Modelica code:
https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/attachment/ticket/85/classDiagramModelicaMedia.png
I need to create a couple of such diagrams and an automated solution would help a lot!
So far, I found this article about Modelica CDV (class diagram viewer):
https://www.modelica.org/events/modelica2006/Proceedings/sessions/Session1c1.pdf
but not a ready to use tool. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with SystemModeler and Mathematica. The relevant function is a little bit hidden, but it's there. Here's an example:

```
WSMLink`Library`WSMDependencyGraph["Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.Spring"]
```

[image: SystemModeler class diagram]

When hovering over the classes, the full name appears:
[image: Full name of a class in SystemModeler]

The object returned from the function includes a Graph, so you can operate on it with all the [graph functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphsAndNetworks.html) in Mathematica. Also the function takes the same arguments as Graph, so you can get different graph layouts if needed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any specific suggestions, but you might find that a tool like OpenModelica could extract and output sufficient information to construct such diagrams.  It seems to have many command line switches for outputting lots of information (debugging and otherwise).

Comment: I already tried OpenModelica 1.9.0. In the GUI I could not find such an option, but command line switches might help, thanks. Other ideas I might try are the Eclipse plugin and OneModelica.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I meant the command line tool (omc).  It has a bunch of flags you can set to extract information.  Some are for debugging, but might be useful to extract such information.

Comment: I opened a ticket to ask about this functionality here: https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/4586