# How to show the hierarchy of a Modelica library?

Tags: hierarchy, modelica

Assuming I have a Modelica library built by others, I wanna know the details and rewrite this library? how could I know the inheritance hierarchy of the components in this library?

The following picture is an example, but I am not sure how to generate this kind of hierarchy diagram.

[image]

Comment: It seems that what you're interested in is the instance hierarchy combined with the class inheritance hierarchy.
As far as I know there is no tool that generates the inheritance hierarchy (of classes, not the components as you say above, for that is the instance hiearchy). Hopefully somebody else knows of such a tool.

Comment: A while back we had something like ModelicaML which could walk a Modelica library and build some UML diagram out of it with the inheritance hierarchy. Unfortunately, because is based on an old Eclipse is no longer supported and we haven't found the resources to update it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607206/modelica-class-diagrams

Comment: @matth, I have used Wolfram System Modeler, it is great, but a lot of libraries only support Dymola. that is a pity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experimented with drawing such diagrams, and with limited success I must admit. For non-trivial examples the graph gets pretty big, especially when you combine the inheritance and component views. Do you know if your image was made by a tool or improved manually?

Here is Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Examples.CoupledClutches for example. The graph is made with GraphViz.

[image]

Comment: PS: Some Modelica models really make use of multiple inheritance...

Comment: The picture above is made manually. It is about a commercial library. Could GraphViz generate the hierarchy diagram automatically?

Comment: GraphViz can be used to generate diagrams with such contents, and is capable of handling really large graphs with good performance. It also enables certain kinds of grouping, as shown above. However, you still need to generate a data file in the DOT "programming language".

Comment: However, the fundamental question is unanswered: is such a diagram really helpful? My feeling is that the information more or less explodes in your face. What would you use it for?

Comment: My original idea is that a hierarchy diagram would help understand the structure of new libraries, so you don't need to check each line of code in each component. Regarding the information explosion, I think it might be more concise with a limited level of the hierarchy. Even though this might be not feasible, but it still helps newbies to Modelica to understand the idea of object-oriented modeling. Is it possible for you to share some examples of Graphviz and Modelica?

Comment: Drop me an e-mail to dag.brueck (at) 3ds.com.

Comment: @DagB I tried the UML feature today to understand one complicated inheritance, and it did help.

Comment: @matth happy to hear that, suggestions for improvements are welcome. Btw, you also find that some classes in MSL have really complex dependencies...