# Modelica class graphs

Tags: graph, relationship, modelica

Looking for best practices where graphs are used to describe relationships between Modelica models. For example, component hierarchy, inheritance, dependencies between packages, combinations of all the above, etc.

The real problem is to find a good compromise between information and diagram complexity, especially for industrial-scale models.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. It's perfectly fine if it is not Modelica, but related.

*Note: This questions was flagged as "not meeting Stackoverflow guidelines" (?), hence I had to edit it. That means the earlier replies were to the original wording.*

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607206/modelica-class-diagrams
related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62118653/how-to-show-the-hierarchy-of-a-modelica-library

Comment: Related, but this question is more about good examples of the end result, not tools to create graphs. The #1 problem is to find what is useful, #2 tools to achieve it. :-)

Comment: Maybe you find this blog post relevant? https://waterprogramming.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/pycharm-as-a-python-ide-for-generating-uml-diagrams/

Comment: Apparently this needs an extension of the simple graph concept in graph theory. Something like that could benefit from the existing concepts of Hypergraphs, Multigraphs, graphs with hyper nodes, ... and probably still purpose-specific adjustments and refinements are needed

Comment: @AtiyahElsheikh, well let's not get too exuberant here. I would be fine with something as primitive as SysML, if we could find a good compromise between detail and clarity.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really have any good examples, so I just share some opinions.

1. There should be two kinds of graphs.
   My thought is there must be two kinds of graphs, one is simplified, which is about the equation structure, and the other one is detailed, which is about the inheritance and dependencies, combination, and all the other stuff. 
   Whatever simulation tool or language you use, in the end, simulation is about how to solve equations, especially nonlinear and complex equations. so if you could tell the users which equation belongs to which component or is generated by which connection, it would be really helpful. One of the issues I often struggle to solve is to find which equations cause nonlinearity and takes too much CPU time to do iterations. Right now, Dymola provides users options to see the final equation structures, but it doesn't show which equation belongs to which components, as far as I know, Wolfram System Modeler does.
   As to the detailed information, I think [sourcetrail](https://www.sourcetrail.com/#intro) is a good example, although it is designed for C++. Interactivity GUI is what attracts my eyes, especially for modelers, so imagine if you see a very detailed dependency diagram of different models, it is hard for anyone to get useful information, so it must be interactive like the `sorcetrail` does, so it could be readable for human.
2. My ideas about the detailed graph.
   I think every piece of information is useful, just like Wikipedia, the key point is how to organize the information.

- Firstly let's take `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Examples.HeatingMOSInverter` as an example. In the following screenshot, we could apparently see there are different Loops related to 2 different domains, which are Electrical and Thermal. So the first rule we should establish is to divide a large model into subsystems based on different domains.
  [image]
- Secondly, let's take `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Examples.CauerLowPassAnalog` as an example, which only includes electrical components from `Modelica.Electrical`. Although this model just includes electrical components, there are a few `Loops` in this model, so it would be definitely better to understand if we could split the model into smaller Loops when generating a class dependency diagram. In the end, there would be two kinds of 1-domain subsystems: Loop and Branch, which are connected by dummy connectors.
  [image]
- Thirdly, let's take the electrical part of `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Examples.HeatingResistor` as the example, marked by the green square.
  [image]
  The class dependency diagram of this kind of 1-domain model would be like the following picture, although the following screenshot is about another example, it could explain that even for the 1-domain model, it is hard to link this class dependency diagram with your real models.
  [image]
  So we should keep the model's topology structure when generating a class dependency diagram. There are different layers in this diagram: Basis layer, Abstract components layer,  Directly used components layer, Model layer. To make the diagram more clear, it could also be 3D. It should look like this:
  [image]
  I think it should be the library developer's duty to adopt good hierarchies to make this diagram look clear and clean. For example, all Abstract components should be `partial model`, so it could easy to recognize them. Or there could be an extra marker variable in each class to mark that the class belongs to which layer. For now, we could use all partial models as `Abstract components`, all non-partial models as `Directly used components`, which could make the diagram unclear， but it is better than nothing.
  Note: there are two important relationships between different layers: Extends and Instantiates, it could be marked by different lines or colors.
  [image]
  When it comes to multi-domain modeling, there should be two separate class dependency diagrams that are connected through these multi-domain components.
  [image]
  To summarize, I think we should generate a class dependency diagram for a single Loop that only includes 1-domain components, and then combine all the diagrams for a single Loop, we will get the whole diagram of the whole model. So in some way, we could keep the original model's topology structure.

Comment: I think your distinction between the two kinds of graphs is important. In my question I was in particular looking for the second kind, the model/package description. I agree that sourcetrail is interesting if you want that level of detail. But what is needed with less detail and a non-interactive view?

Comment: @DagB, Please check the updated answer, see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Two other sources are https://ep.liu.se/ecp/157/073/ecp19157073.pdf and https://modelica.org/events/modelica2006/Proceedings/sessions/Session1c1.pdf.

Comment: Seen the paper(2006) before, but sadly Modelica CDV isn't available anymore. There is definitely a huge need for the Library hierarchy visualization, I guess UML could be a good option, but if it could reflect the model's original topology structure, it could be better.